# How big around does the trunk of a Fuyu Persimmon tree get?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, growth, persimmon

How big around does the trunk of a Fuyu Persimmon get?

I have a newly planted Fuyu Persimmon tree that we are wanting to build a deck around. I want to make sure I give the tree enough of a hole to grow in. How much room is it likely the tree will need?

Comment: Hi there, adding a picture helps and telling us where in the world you are helps even more.